# A manga about a king

Tags: story-identification, manga

Remember watching it a couple years back
Its a full coloured manga? About a king that can teleport into a diablo world to level up

Last chapter i remember was our mc fighting enemy army alone on a bridge

Answer (score 1):

This should be [The Live](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-live). It's about a king who has been betrayed and killed by his closest allies, and after dying, he gains the ability to "teleport" into a game-like world. In this world, he levels up and gains new skills to take revenge on those who betrayed him.

Comment: Im afraid it aint the live